# Cannot 'docker ps' without sudo - even after adding my account to the docker group

Tags: docker, sudo, ubuntu-22.04

I am on Ubuntu 22.04 and I installed docker with:**sudo apt install docker.io** I did make my user part of the docker group and doing **groups $(whoami)** shows that my account **jack** is part of the **docker** group.

`sudo docker ps` works just fine but `docker ps` gives me:

```
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///home/jack/.docker/desktop/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

I am at a loss, why do I need sudo? I was able to run docker without sudo on Ubuntu 20.04 and then I re-built my machine with Ubuntu 22.04 and now I require sudo, is there something that I forgot to do?

`docker --version` gave me:`Docker version 20.10.12, build 20.10.12-0ubuntu4`

Doing:`ll ~/.docker/desktop/docker.sock` gave me: `srwxrwxr-x 1 jack jack 0 May  9 10:37 /home/jack/.docker/desktop/docker.sock=`

I did reboot.... no change

```
¯\_(ツ)_/¯
```

Comment: Try restarting your machine https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/

Comment: You don't need to reboot, but you _do_ need to log out and back in for group membership changes to take effect for your session. (`groups yourname` shows what's configured for the system, not the current session, so it shows what your group membership will be _next time you log in_; use `id -G` instead to see what it is now)

Comment: ...anyhow, does `lsof` or `fuser` show anything attached to the other end of that socket? You _should_ see the daemon there.

Comment: Also, note that Docker Desktop is a different product with more moving parts / more things to go wrong than Docker itself. (It's also under less-friendly licensing terms; if you _can_ use regular fully-open-source Docker, without Docker Desktop, I strongly recommend it. Moreover, `docker ps` is a regular Docker command; you don't need Docker Desktop to provide it).

Comment: ...you shouldn't _need_ a separate socket under your home directory with the traditional product, which will use group membership for access control to a shared socket location.

Comment: 'shouldm't but yet..' I did nothing funny, I just installed docker with ```apt install docker.io``` I did un-install and re-install but am still stuck on using sudo

Comment: Docker has changed installation procedures multiple times and `apt install docker.io` is not the recommended way. More info here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/

Comment: @HansKilian, point taken. I followed that link and un-installed and re-installed (I tried it before but to add exactly what went wrong I did it again) and while running ```sudo apt-get install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io docker-compose-plugin``` I got:
```invoke-rc.d: initscript docker, action "start" failed.``` and lower down:```Process: 113649 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)``` and even lower down:```Errors were encountered while processing:
 docker-ce```

Answer (score 3):

Faced the same issue, got a workaround for it!
After adding the user to the group `docker`
Just do

```bash
newgrp docker
```

before using docker commands like `docker ps`

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you see  `Is the docker daemon running?` it almost always means that the docker daemon is not running, so start the docker daemon either through UI or command line and try again.